# Add a custom preprocessing function in ImageDataGenerator for gaussian blurring

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am using Image Data Generator to extend my dataset.

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        path_to_train,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode = "sparse",
        color_mode="grayscale")
```

and then

```
history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=20,
        epochs=100
        )
```

The problem is that I want to apply some methods to the input images.
I want to use Gaussian bluring and etc.
But how can I apply it when I directly load it and use model fit.

Can you help me please? Thanks for you advices.

Comment: Please edit your title for something that can help future readers find this question

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/gaussian_filter2d):

```
@tf.function
tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(
    image: tfa.types.TensorLike,
    filter_shape: Union[List[int], Tuple[int], int] = [3, 3],
    sigma: Union[List[float], Tuple[float], float] = 1.0,
    padding: str = 'REFLECT',
    constant_values: tfa.types.TensorLike = 0,
    name: Optional[str] = None
) -> tfa.types.TensorLike
```

You can pass this function in `ImageDataGenerator`:

```
img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    proprocessing_function=tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d
)
```

Comment: thank you!!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In that case, don't hesitate to vote on/accept my answer!