# How to implement custom data generator for images in keras?

Tags: image, keras, data-augmentation

I have used Keras generators through ImageDataGenerator, however I would like to extend it to include some transformations that are currently not included (say Gaussian smoothing). For example,

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range      = 5,
    width_shift_range   = 0.1,
    my_smoothing_kernel = 0.3)
```

where obviously my_smoothing_kernel would be the function I would like to add. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I would then like to use datagan.flow as an input into model.fit as normal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add-a-custom-preprocessing-function-in-imagedatagenerator-for-gaussian-blurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66783142/add-a-custom-preprocessing-function-in-imagedatagenerator-for-gaussian-blurring/66783233#66783233)

Comment: Eerily similar, but not quite. In short, my question is about how to add a custom function to ImageDataGenerator. I know how to actually do the Gaussian blurring, and how to use the preproccessing_function. Basically I would just like to add new functions to ImageDataGenerator, with parameters that I can control.

Comment: Why is it important to you to have custom arguments, instead of a `preprocessing_function`? I see no other option other than subclassing `ImageDataGenerator`, which is essentially re-writing Tensorflow. At that point, you'd be better off using a custom [generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control) or just passing `preprocessing_function`